# Visual Studio 2015 How to remove the Analysis Services Database from the File/Open menu

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Recently, an menu item was added to the Visual Studio 2015 File/Open menu (I guess by updating or adding an extension). The new item is the "Analysis Services Database" and it's the first (!!!) in the file/open which is not very convenient.
Does anyone knows how to completely remove this item from the file/open menu or put at the end of the file/open menu?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go Tools..Customize, Command tab, choose 'File open' at the Menu bar option, and Move down the culprit.